# How to prevent stopping setCurrentItem() on program start?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-viewpager

Helo,

I've got a `ViewPager` with some thousand pages. It scrolls to page 5000 at program start with the method `setCurrentItem(5000)`.

My problem is:

When I start application and tap quickly on the screen, then `setCurrentItem(5000)` doesn't work. It stops at the first item.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `setCurrentItem(5000, false)`. The second parameter is `smoothScroll`, which is `true` by default. If you set it to `false`, the `ViewPager` will "transition immediately" to the `View`.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) for this.